# Spacing Between String and Hiding String

Tags: php

I have tried everything now what i need to do is place a space between a $results

```
 echo "<p><h3>".$results['cname'].$results['csurname']."</h3>" .$results['msisdn']."</p>"
```

Betweeb cname and csurnname I need a spacing, Also i need to hide the msisdn not to display on the screen but it is required to work my page

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put space using blank quotes like

```
echo "<p><h3>".$results['cname']." ".$results['csurname']."</h3>" .$results['msisdn']."</p>";
```

However you can use `$results['msisdn']` anywhere in the script. If you want to use it in form post use it as

```
<input type='hidden' name='msisdn' value="<?php echo $results['msisdn']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<p><h3>".$results['cname'].' '.$results['csurname']."</h3></p>"
```

that's it. You should be still able to use the `$results['msisdn']` on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo "<p><h3>".$results['cname']." ".$results['csurname']."</h3><span style='display:none;'>" .$results['msisdn']."</span></p>"
```

This will hide your content :

```
<span style='display:none;'> content will be hidden </span>
```

Comment: @StingEvony : Cool :D, In stackoverflow we say thanks by accepting the answer and voting up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<p><h3>"." ".$results['cname']." ".$results['csurname']."</h3></p>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='msisdn' value=$results['msisdn']>";
```